# regexp_replace / not contains certain strings

Tags: python, pyspark, regexp-replace

I am trying to make a new column by replacing certain strings.

```
df = df.withColumn('new_key_location', F.regexp_replace('key_location'), ^'Seoul|Jeju|Busan', 'Others')
```

I want to change other location names in the `key_location` column not containing 'Seoul|Jeju|Busan' strings to 'Others'.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use `.isin` or `.like` with a `when().otherwise()` instead of `regexp_replace`.

```py
reqd_cities = ['Seoul', 'Jeju', 'Busan']

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('new_key_location', 
               func.when(func.col('key_location').isin(reqd_cities), func.col('key_location').
                         otherwise(func.lit('Others'))
                         )
               )
```

OR

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('new_key_location', 
               func.when(func.col('key_location').like('%Seoul%') | 
                         func.col('key_location').like('%Jeju%') |
                         func.col('key_location').like('%Busan%'), func.col('key_location')).
               otherwise(func.lit('Others'))
               )
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be more straightforward to use `df.apply`:

```
important_cities = ['Seoul', 'Jeju', 'Busan']
df["new_key_location"] = df["key_location"].apply(lambda x: x if x in important_cities else "Others")
```

but not matching regex should be

```
'^(?!(Seoul|Jeju|Busan))'
```